# How can i read bytes from a very heavy file? then store store them in a String e.g. .pdf .zip .xlsx files

Tags: java, printing, byte, inputstream

im using the `java.nio.file.Files` library and the method works only when i choose tiny files (like *txt, docx, "pdf* but ONLY with a tiny size") and sometimes with a some minutes of delay. But if i choose a very large file with any extension or simply with a more "complex" extension (like *.exe, .pptx, .zip, .rar*, etc) the program clashes¡. it could be great if you give me the name of a up to date libray that has the same functionality as `FileInputStream` and `Files` just because i think the problem is that the library can't support large sizes or maybe a brilliant sorcerer who can solve my issue. Very Thanks¡

following the method im using:

```
private void readBytes(){
    try{
        boolean completed=false;
        File file=null;
        JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
        if(chooser.showOpenDialog(this)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            file=new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile().getPath());
            byte[]bytes=Files.readAllBytes(file.getAbsoluteFile().toPath());
            String output="File size: "+file.length()+" bytes\n\n";
            for(int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++){
                output+=bytes[i]+"  ";
                if(i!=0){                        
                    if(i%10==0)output+="\n";
                }
                if(i==(int)file.length()-1)completed=true;
            }
            if(completed)JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The reading has completed and the file size is: "+file.length()+" bytes");
            else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The reading has not completed","Error",0);
            jTextArea1.setText(output);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to load large files entirely into memory, nor to store binary data in Strings. What is the outer problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: trying to get something like this
http://imgur.com/FLOVeJu
omg idk how to insert the image

Comment: practically to obtain every byte from the binary file or any file and print an array of bytes as a string. I already used the MappedByteBuffer method below and just list the bytes of files under 200kb if larger it crashes or sometimes takes a long time to show the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Files.readAllBytes` is not recommended for large files as it loads into memory. 
 May be you could use MappedByteBuffer.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class ReadFileWithMappedByteBuffer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile
                ("test.txt", "r");
        FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = inChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, inChannel.size());
        buffer.load();  
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print((char) buffer.get());
        }
        buffer.clear(); // do something with the data and clear/compact it.
        inChannel.close();
        aFile.close();
    }
}
```

Please refer http://howtodoinjava.com/java-7/nio/3-ways-to-read-files-using-java-nio/ for more options

Comment: Thanks bro, if i am not bothering. The program now returned this weird text like "$ﾀﾐﾀﾐ@"  and its stored in `char` variables. what should i do if i want my program to return something like "0 71 -3 0 -10 60 32" Thanks again

Comment: For binary file printing doesn't make any sense I just given an example here it suppose to print that way